# How to make a static class value a method call like a getter property

Tags: typescript

I have this class:

```
export class Vec2 {
  static unit = new Vec2(1, 1)

  get clone(): Vec2 {
    return new Vec2(this.x, this.y)
  }

  constructor(readonly x: number, readonly y: number) {}


  scale(k: number) {
    this.x *= k
    this.y *= k
  }
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
let ten_v = Vec2.unit.scale(10)
let twenty_v = Vec2.unit.scale(20)
```

As you can see I start from a unit vector and scale it to get the vector I want.

This is the API I want no `Vec2.unit()` or `Vec2.unit.clone.scale(10)`.

The problem with this is, `scale` method modifies the unit vector which is a static object, and I don't want that.

So I would like a static getter property just like object instances have getter properties that expands into method calls. Like `clone` in this example but `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting ECMAScript 2015 or higher (which you, let's be honest, probably should be in 2022), you can actually just declare getters with the `static` modifier.

```
static get UNIT() {
  return new Vec2(1, 1);
}
```

But read on, because I want to challenge the frame of this question a bit. The frame challenge is this: Why is your vector mutable *at all*? Vectors are nice mathematical objects, so why not have all of those functions just return new ones?

```
export class Vec2 {
  static UNIT = new Vec2(1, 1);

  readonly x: number;
  readonly y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  scale(k: number) {
    return new Vector(this.x * k, this.y * k);
  }

}
```

Now you don't have to worry about whether or not existing vectors get modified, because vectors *never* get modified. You don't need `clone` anymore, since there's never a use case to intentionally have two identical-looking vectors. And the static field is fine since, again, everything you can possibly do to it is immutable.

I've been working with the Minecraft Bukkit API, and it has a mutable `Vector` class. So I can speak from personal experience when I say that it is a *royal pain* to work with. Every time you want to modify a vector, you defensively `.clone` because you're not sure if the function you called just did that or not, and anytime you *want* to modify an existing vector, you end up assigning it back because, again, you're not sure if they gave you the real vector or a clone. *Sometimes* it's documented, but sometimes it's not. So really, save yourself and everyone who uses your library the immense headache and just make it immutable.

Comment: I also have functions like `scale_in(x: number) { return this.clone.scale(x) }`. I don't use this version because of memory performance.